# Dynamically changing dates in command Prompt

Tags: windows, command-line, csv

I am trying to write a command prompt in changing file names for a monthly report I run and am automating.

I have the export file as "Export.xlsx", and I want to change it to 02 2018.xlsx, 03 2018.xlsx, etc, without having to go into the code each month and change the number. Is there a way that Windows can sense what numbers are in the folder already and add 1 number to the file name? Here is the current lines I have. If the arrangement of numbers needs to change for this to be possible, that is just fine.

rename "File Path\Projects_Log.csv" "03 18 Projects_Log.csv"

Comment: (1) Do you want it to use the *current* month, or do you want to find the highest existing file and add one? (2) Do you want “MM YYYY” or “MM YY”? (3) What’s the relationship between `Export.xlsx` and `File Path\Projects_Log.csv`? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

To rename the files with date time, try this command:

```
ren e:\test2\test.txt  test_%date:~10,4%%date:~7,2%%date:~4,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%.txt
```